# Display red channel of image with NumPy and Matplotlib only

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, matrix

I'm trying to display the red channel of an image using Matplotlib.pyplot and NumPy only. Can someone explain, why I get different images for the following two codes?

Code #1:

```
R = numpy.copy(img)           # copy image into new array
R[:,:,1]=0                    # set green channel to 0
R[:,:,2]=0                    # set blue channel to 0
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(R)
matplotlib.plyplot.show()     # display new image
```

Code #2:

```
R = numpy.zeros(img.shape)    # create array of 0-s with same dimensions as image
R[:,:,0]=img[:,:,0]           # copy red channel values into array of 0-s
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(R)
matplotlib.plyplot.show()     # display new image
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify a data type in your `numpy.zeros()` call:

```py
numpy.zeros(img.shape)
```

That way, `R` is of type `float64`, and most of its values are greater or equal `1`, such that you see "clipping" in your plots.

The easiest way to fix that, would be to set up the proper data type:

```py
numpy.zeros(img.shape, numpy.uint8)
```

Then, both versions produce equal results.

The `numpy.copy(img)` in the first version uses the data type from the copy source, such that `R` has the proper data type `numpy.uint8` right from the start.

Alternatively, you could also modify your `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()` call:

```py
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(R / 255)
```

So, all values in `R` are properly mapped to `[0.0 ... 1.0]`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In the first code you are probably using uint8 type, and in the second you are casting to float... `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()` shows different outputs to different types